# Animate UICollectionView contentInset adjustment

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Is there any way to animate the `invalidateLayout()` call on a UICollectionView layout?  I have a collectionView with a custom layout, and a view that is animating on top of that collectionView.  I would like to animate the repositioning of the cells in the collection view (much like a default UIScrollView implementation would do), but calling `invalidateLayout()` during an animation block repositions the cells with a fade animation, rather than an interpolation of the frames.

Is there any way to dictate the type of animation used in the layout change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, and hope this helps someone else.  The trick was simply to call `collectionView.performBatchUpdtes(nil, completion: nil)` inside the animation block.